# SelectSingleNode Return Value

Tags: xml, vb.net

I'm working on a school project where I'm using XML data from an online data source to create a small pre-flight briefing tool. The code is intended to be able to search the XML document and get various piece of data (airport code, wind direction/speed, visibility, etc...) and display the data. With a decent bit of scouring the internet, I found a rather simple code that should work.

```
Dim doc As XmlDocument = New XmlDocument()
    doc.Load("http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requesttype=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1&mostRecentForEachStation=constraint&stationString=KDAB")
    Dim airportcode As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("//station_id").Value
    Label1.Text = airportcode
```

As you can guess, the label's text doesn't change. I've done research on this and it has something to do with XML Namespaces, but it's just a bit too far over my head for me to understand.

Thanks in advance for the help. -Michael

Comment: *the label's text doesn't change* from what to what? Your code selects the first node for `//station_id`, and never looks for anything else. If it's set once, it won't change to any other value, because you never look for any other value. As a note: it's always important to add a tag for the language you're using, because it's always relevant to the question. If you're using VB.Net, add a tag that indicates that fact, so that the question gets to the attention of the people that are familiar with that language.

Comment: have you tried ".InnerText" instead of ".Value"?

Answer (score 1):

Other possibility using XDocument:

```
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("http://aviationweather.gov/adds/dataserver_current/httpparam?dataSource=metars&requesttype=retrieve&format=xml&hoursBeforeNow=1&mostRecentForEachStation=constraint&stationString=KDAB")
Dim airportcode As String = doc...<station_id>.Value
Label1.Text = airportcode
```

Answer (score 0):

The contents of the node you have selected is in a child node. You need to add `firstchild`:

```
Dim airportcode As String = doc.SelectSingleNode("//station_id").FirstChild.Value
```